# Add UIBarButtonItem to UINavigationController contained in a UITabBarController from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

**EDIT: Solution : add the buttons to UIViewControllers and no to UINavigationControllers**

My application's root view controller is a uitabbarcontroller who contains an array of 5 navigation controllers, all initialized in app delegate.
All works good but I have just one problem : I can't add any button in the navigation bar of the controllers contained in the tabbarcontroller from the app delegate. I can set their navigation bar's title, their navigation bar's background etc but when I add a button in their navigation bar, I have no error but the button isn't displayed.

Is anyone know the reason of that ? Is it forbidden to do that ?

Precision 1: I use .xib files for views, I don't use any storyboard.

Precision 2: this is the code I'm using to create the button for each controller :

```
UIBarButtonItem *myBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-chrono"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

[ret.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myBarBtn animated:YES];
```

Precision 3: when I copy this code in each navigation controller viewDidLoad method, it works

**EDIT: it's not a problem with the image**, the problem is the same when I use initWithTitle method to create the UIBarButtonItem

Comment: Are you sure your project contains image named "icon-chrono"? I have tried same code in one of my project and it runs fine. My only guess is that image might not be added in the project.

Comment: Hi, thank's for your response. Yes i'm sure this image exists, I'd check twice and this image is correctly loaded when I execute this code from a controller's viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I find another way to do that (I created a UINavigationController extension who create navbar buttons and call it in my controllers viewDidLoad method) so I'm not blocked but I really would like understand what happens here. I thank it was a restriction of Xcode but If it works for you it's strange. Don't understand where I'm wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

add **.png** or **.jpg** behind image name may be this will help you.

like this.

```
 UIBarButtonItem *myBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-chrono.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

    [ret.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myBarBtn animated:YES];
```

**OR**

Click on your project -> Build Phases -> Copy bundle resource, and see there, your image exist or not. if not then add it using **"+"** button tapped. see below image.
[image]

Comment: I'd just tried both solutions, don't work. It's not an image problem, a button with a title isn't displayed too. And yet when I check in the app delegate execution the navigation controller's navigation item, the right button is present and non-nil. But when the view controller is loaded, the navigation item is nil

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'd just found the problem ...

My UITabController contains an array of 5 UINavigationController who each contain a UIViewController as root view controller.
I tried to add the buttons on UINavigationControllers instead of UIViewControllers ... If I add the button directly in the UIViewControllers it's working !